# Stub global cookies variable in Rspec Rails test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

The Rspec test looks like this:

```
RSpec.describe Api::UsersController, type: :controller do
    describe 'POST #create' do
        subject { post :create, params: create_params }

        context '...' do
```

In the controller, I use:

```
cookies.permanent[:foo] == 'bar'
```

However, I'm getting:

```
NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `cookies' for #<Api::UsersController:0x000000137702f0>
```

Another SO question has an answer that says to add `type: :request` to `describe`, but this causes other errors. I'd rather just completely stub out `cookies` so `cookies.permanent[:foo] == 'bar'` is always false. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

By default controllers in rails-api don't include the middleware that handles cookies. If you need cookies then you need to add that middleware:

```
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies
```

For the above problem, you need to include

```
ActionController::Cookies
```

in your spec files

Comment: Where do I add those? I tried adding `config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies` in `application.rb`, but it didn't do anything

Comment: You need to add it on spec_helper